# What is the consequence in deleting my own off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This has happened:
I asked a question and it is marked as **off-topic**. After corresponding about it I see, the question is really off-topic, because it was only a bad-debug-problem. Nevertheless I've learned something from the user comments. 
So what would be the consequence if I delete this question? Will the answer and all the comments be lost? Also the comments which haven't been read by the receivers?
Will the answerer and commentators lost their earned reputation? This would be a bit unfair.

Comment: If the answer is upvoted you can't delete it. If not the answerer is unlikely to have any reputation to lose so which is it?

Comment: If it's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789817/items-in-qmap-get-lost) you're talking about, you can't delete it because (as @Robert notes) it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, the answer is accepted and upvoted and also some comments are upvoted. Question is not downvoted, not yet. But I've read in this community, that nobody should answer off-topic questions (its a bit nasty) because the askers are help vampires. I've not enough rep to loose (or are there negative points)? So you mean I should be happy someone was helping me an delete the question?

Comment: Try deleting the question if you like, you'll find the system will not allow it.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, this is the question, and now I'm happy because it's not in my area of responsibility :-
)